# Maven run Profiles without active profile

Tags: bash, maven

I am trying to run from bash maven with profile that is deactivate and not run the active one.
So I have 2 profiles:
1. first which is default active = true
2. second which is default active = false

```
<profile>
        <id>second</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
...
 ...
<profile>
        <id>first</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
```

But i want to run only second.
so I am executing:

```
mvn package -P !first,second
```

but I get :

```
bash: !first: event not found
```

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Ok found it just wrap with single quotes https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/how-to-echo-a-bang

Comment: Could you update answer? It is not obvious for not unix users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it just wrap with single quotes [echo-bang-in-unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/how-to-echo-a-bang)

```
mvn package -P '!first,second'
```